# Wordpress Custom URL Rewrite Entry in htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Simple thing I'm trying to do - just upgraded a site to use wordpress, there is ONE page in particular i do not want to 301 and want to retain its original url

the original url is

/freerecords.htm

here is what i added to my htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/freerecords.htm [NC]

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^/freerecords.htm$ /index.php\?page_id=793 [L,NC]
```

problem is the above isn't working -i think i'm pretty close...

i don't want to use wordpress built in php url rewriting functions - i just want to do this in the htaccess

any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

instead of directly changing from .htaccess use setting of permalinks in your admin panel to do URL rewriting

And also check the permissions to .htaccess file before doing permalink changes.

Or you can also change wordpress .htaccess file from the theme file editor provided on admin side

http://davidwalsh.name/wordpress-htaccess

Comment: Thanks, but none of the above helps. I do not want to use permalinks in admin panel, permissions on htaccess are fine and i understand I can change the htaccess file from the admin side - thats not the problem

Answer (score 0):

If you want a 301 redirect, you need this to happen before the wordpress related rules:

```
RewriteRule ^freerecords.htm /index.php?page_id=793 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

This redirects the browser using a 301 redirect. Like all redirects, the browser's URL address bar will now say `/index.php?page_id=793`.

If you didn't want a 301 redirect, your old rules have a leading slash in them that is probably making it not work. Your last line has a leading slash in the regular expression that makes it so it will never match anything:

```
# was here---v
RewriteRule ^freerecords.htm$ /index.php\?page_id=793 [L,NC]
```

Comment: I dont want to change the url and want to avoid a 301

Comment: @Loren must have misread your question, just follow the directions under **"If you didn't want a 301 redirect"** then

Comment: oh man i'm sorry... reading all this while in a phone meeting.. lol

Comment: I've tried adding that but it doesn't work - thats why i'm so confused

Comment: @Loren you removed the slash? This works fine for any page I want to route without using wordpress.

Comment: RewriteRule ^freerecords.htm$ /index.php\?page_id=793 [NC,L]

Comment: added that, still no go tho =( sends me to 404 page